# Can I detect activity launch in intent-filter? Android

Tags: java, android

```
activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999999999">
            <action android:name="com.android.settings.Settings" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is **AndroidManifest.xml** contents.
Then in **MainActivity.java**:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Do some actions that will be in `onCreate()` if detect working.
```

Comment: Emm actually question is not so clear. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I detect activity launch in intent-filter?

The easiest approach would be have different activity triggered by said filter that would, in its `onCreate()` put some data into Bundle and then chain-call your `MainActivity` and `finish()` (so transient one, no UI). Then you can know by checking what's in Bundle (if `getExtras()` returns any).

You can also check what's in Intent itself, but depending on your filters it may require bit more work than transient activity mentioned previously.

```
<intent-filter android:priority="999999999">
```

This makes no effect at all, because the `android:priority` value must be an integer greater than [SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_LOW_PRIORITY) and less than [SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY) which means range between `-1000` and `1000`. Any other values are ignored and priority falls back to default `0` (docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#setPriority(int))).